# Git clone error after OS X Mountain Lion update

Tags: github, osx-mountain-lion, brunch

I just updated my MBP to OSX 10.8 and am trying to start a new project with brunch.io which by default uses coffeescript and I prefer javascript so I need to clone the simple js skeleton. So something like this:

```
brunch new <someprojectname> --skeleton https://github.com/brunch/simple-js-skeleton.git
```

Which is what I have used previously and it worked fine. But today I am getting the following error:

```
error: Git clone error: /bin/sh: git: command not found
```

I really don't know how to fix this...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can download Apple's official collection of developer command line utilities (which includes git) by either:

- Opening Xcode, going to Preferences > Downloads and clicking the install button next to 'Command Line Utilities'
- Going to [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads), and downloading "Xcode 4.4 Command Line Tools for OSX 10.8" from the Xcode 4.4 category

Comment: I guess the real problem is that Xcode was upgraded (replaced) along the way, so the command-line tools are missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` if the appropiate `PATH` is set. Did you install git via macports? The update probably dropped the `/opt/bin` or `/opt/local/bin` from the PATH.

Comment: I can't even find .bashrc or .bash_profile. In terminal I type: ls -a and the only thing beginning with .bash is .bash_history... also I'm did a quick check and don't have macports installed. it was awhile ago that I installed git, I don't remember how or when I did actually...

Comment: This tips works for me. My profile is called `.profile` and it is in the root of my home folder. This is in there: `export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin/:$PATH"`. I did not need to reinstall anything, but make sure you restart Terminal after you have added this.

Answer (score 3):

I got everything working again. Apparently the update to Mountain Lion dropped git altogether. Simply downloading the install package from [here](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) and running it has everything working again.

Comment: Couldn't install it after download, got a message that the package was from an unidentified developer and that my security settings only allow installs from Apple Store!!! Just installed Mountain Lion, so I really need to check these security settings!...

Comment: Go to Prefernces -> Security -> check any sorce instead only App Store

Comment: I don't think it drops git, I think it just removes it from the PATH somehow. Femaref's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to change your security settings go to System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Change Allow Applications downloaded from --> Anywhere. There is a chance your security settings would be locked in that case press the lock at the bottom left on the pref pane.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://dwainm.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/mountain-lion-git-command-not-found-2-min-fix/) article:

1. open your ~/.bash_profile, if you use nano it would be :
   $ sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
2. add this line to the file:
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/
3. Save & close the file and type on the terminal:
   $ source ~/.bash_profile